# MVVMCross PictureChooserTask load exception

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am creating an Android project with MVVMCross and Xamarin on Mac using Xamarin Studio.  Everything has been going terrific until I got to needing to use the camera.  I downloaded and installed the PictureChooserTask plugin.  The issue I am having is after adding the dll's to the Android project and calling:

Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded ();

I now can't run the application.  It fails during startup with the following error:

Missing method AddOrOverwriteFrom in assembly .**override**/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Droid.dll

Comment: Are all your assemblies from the same version?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to just manually register the singleton type using the following:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxPictureChooserTask, MvxPictureChooserTask> ();
```